# Partial CSS border around a DIV

Tags: html, css

I am using the CSS below to get an incomplete border look around a DIV.
But can only get it to be blank on either the left side or the right side of the div. How can I get it to have that "incomplete look" on both sides?

```css
.incomplete-box {
  border: solid 1px #f00;
  border-right: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.incomplete-box::after,
.incomplete-box::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 30%;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #f00;
  right: 0;
}

.incomplete-box::after {
  top: 0;
}

.incomplete-box::before {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="incomplete-box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore in quae incidunt deleniti minima quibusdam, suscipit dignissimos cumque officia ullam.
</div>
```

Comment: I changed your border from white to red so that we can actually see it

Comment: consider reading **all** the answers, the interesting ones are at the very bottom, don't stick to the most upvoted or accepted answer